# User defined natvis files in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, debuggervisualizer, natvis

I'm trying to use new debug visualizers in my project, but something happened to Visual Studio and it does not pick up my natvis files anymore. I tried copying them to `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Visualizers` as well as to `\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers` but it still fails.

It did work a week ago, but something has broken since then.

I tried repairing Visual Studio but it didn't help.

I tried enabling `EnableNatvisDiagnostics` in the registry but I didn't get any diagnostic messages in the `Output window`.

The preinstalled natvis files were working fine though. So I tried to remove one of the preinstalled natvis files: `stl.natvis` from `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers` but Visual Studio was still showing `vector` as if it had access to `stl.natvis` file. Does anybody know how to fix this? Is there any other location where Visual Studio loads natvis files from? Maybe there is a registry key for that?

PS. I tried using `ProcessMonitor` to find out the location from which Visual Studio loads natvis files, but I couldn't find any references in `ProcessMonitor`s logs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally figured this out. Natvis visualizers do not work when [Edit and Continue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx) is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for posting.  This had me totally frustrated with it until I found your answer.

Comment: I still have the problem for qt5.natvis. Trick didn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: If this is the case then I wonder what magic makes *stl* always has its own natvis enabled even in edit and continue?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

Check Tools->Options->Debugging->General->**Show raw structure of objects in variables windows**.
It should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that custom NatVis files (those in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 201x\Visualizers`) are not used if you use the ReSharper Test Runner to debug a test. However the built-in ones, e.g. for `std::vector` are working.

If you run a test regularly (i.e., **Debug** -> **Start Debugging**, likely F5) your custom NatVis files are loaded and used.